# Scons copy header files to build directory

Tags: python, scons

I'm trying to copy a number of headers files from my source directories to an 'includes' directory inside my build directory using scons. My target is a static library and I want to distribute it together with its relevant headers. The expected end result:

```
build
|-- objects -> .o output files for constructing libmclib.a
|-- includes
|   |-- foo.h
|   `-- bar.h
`-- libmclib.a
```

My SConstruct:

```py
#!python
target = 'mock'

env = Environment(LINKCOM = "$LINK -o $TARGET $SOURCES $LINKFLAGS $CCFLAGS")
Export('env', 'target')

build_base = 'build'
SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir=build_base, duplicate=0)

# remove build directory
if GetOption('clean'):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', build_base])
```

My SConscript:

```py
#!python
Import('env')

# ...
# other stuff to build 'mclib_target'
# ...

def copy_header_files(target, source, env):
    Mkdir(target)
    header_files = []
    for d in env['CPPPATH']:
        header_files += Glob(d + "/*.h")
    for f in header_files:
        Copy(target, f)

# copy all relevant header files
env.Command("includes", mclib_target, copy_header_files)
```

Scons does call 'copy_header_files' with arguments '["build/includes"], ["build/libmclib.a"]', but for some reason 'Mkdir' doesn't create the includes directory. Also 'Copy' seems to do nothing. If I however call Mkdir like this:

```py
env.Command("includes", mclib_target, [Mkdir('$TARGET')])
```

it seems to work well. How to fix/work around this? I'm also quite new to Scons so any alternative for doing this task are welcome. I'm using scons 2.5.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use "`Install()`" instead of "`Copy()`". Also the `Mkdir()` shouldn't be necessary, SCons creates all intermediate folders for its targets automatically.

Finally, allow me some comments about your general approach: I'd rather not mix "building" with "installing/preparing for packaging". The "`variant_dir`" option is there to help you with building several "variants" (release, optimized, debug, ARM-specific,...) from the same source files (let's say you have a folder named "src"). By passing the name of the current "build" directory into your "src" SConscript you're embedding variant-specific knowledge into your local build description, meaning that you'll have to touch it with every variant that you add.
Instead, you should move the "`Install/Package`" steps into the top-level SConstruct...where you have global knowledge about which variants get built. From there you can copy (= Install) the final files to a separate subfolder, e.g. `distribution`, and archive that one instead.

For a simple example of how to handle variants right in SCons, check out the repo https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_talks and there the "`pyconde_2013/examples/exvar`" folder.

Comment: This is it! I replaced the env.Command with env.Install in a for loop to copy every header from the build directory (duplicate set to 1) to a 'distro' directory. I also moved install related stuff to the SConstruct script since that is indeed a better approach. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The *Mkdir* and *Copy* operations that you are using are Action factories for use in Command definitions, described in [Platform-Independent File System Manipulation](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-factories):

> SCons provides a number of platform-independent functions, called
>   factories, that perform common file system manipulations like copying,
>   moving or deleting files and directories, or making directories. **These
>   functions are factories because they don't perform the action at the
>   time they're called, they each return an Action object that can be
>   executed at the appropriate time.**

I have always had problems trying to use these functions within my own action functions. Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't think these functions can be used outside of the immediate list of operations in the Command builder.

Instead I use the platform-independent functions in python for creating directories and copying files, such as [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) and [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy).